# Audio Output Routes for AirPlay

Tags: ios, audio, ios5, audiotoolbox

I have looked but can't find a way to access the Audio Output Routes so i can detect if the audio is coming out via AirPlay.

This is what i found in the Documentation for iOS 5.0

```
kAudioSessionOutputRoute_AirPlay
```

Discussion

> These strings are used as values for the kAudioSession_AudioRouteKey_Type key for the   dictionary associated with the kAudioSession_AudioRouteKey_Outputs array.

I can't find a way to get access to the kAudioSession_AudioRouteKey_Outputs array.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if Bassem seems to have found a solution, for completion's sake, here's how to detect whether the current output route is AirPlay or not:

```
- (BOOL)isAirPlayActive{
    CFDictionaryRef currentRouteDescriptionDictionary = nil;
    UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(currentRouteDescriptionDictionary);
    AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteDescription, &dataSize, &currentRouteDescriptionDictionary);
    if (currentRouteDescriptionDictionary) {
        CFArrayRef outputs = CFDictionaryGetValue(currentRouteDescriptionDictionary, kAudioSession_AudioRouteKey_Outputs);
        if (outputs) {
            if(CFArrayGetCount(outputs) > 0) {
                CFDictionaryRef currentOutput = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(outputs, 0);
                CFStringRef outputType = CFDictionaryGetValue(currentOutput, kAudioSession_AudioRouteKey_Type);
                return (CFStringCompare(outputType, kAudioSessionOutputRoute_AirPlay, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo);
            }
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Keep in mind that you have to `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>` and link against the AudioToolbox framework.

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 6, the recommended approach for this would be using `AVAudioSession` (the C-based `AudioSession` API is deprecated as of iOS 7).

```
let currentRoute = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute
```

`currentRoute` returns an `AVAudioSessionRouteDescription`, a very simple class with two properties: `inputs` and `outputs`. Each of these is an optional array of `AVAudioSessionPortDescriptions`, which provides the information we need about the current route:

```
if let outputs = currentRoute?.outputs as? [AVAudioSessionPortDescription] {
    // Usually, there will be just one output port (or none), but let's play it safe...
    if let airplayOutputs = outputs.filter { $0.portType == AVAudioSessionPortAirPlay } where !airplayOutputs.isEmpty {
        // Connected to airplay output...
    } else {
        // Not connected to airplay output...
    }
}
```

The `portType` is the useful info here... see the [`AVAudioSessionPortDescription` docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSessionPortDescription_class/index.html) for the `AVAudioSessionPort...` constants that describe each input/output port type, such as line in/out, built in speakers, Bluetooth LE, headset mic etc.

Also, don't forget to respond appropriate to route changes by subscribing to the `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification`.

Comment: Can you explain in what scenario would the outputs array be non-nil but empty?

Answer (score 0):

```
CFArray *destinations;
CFNumber *currentDest;

// Get the output destination list
AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OutputDestinations, nil, destinations);

// Get the index of the current destination (in the list above)
AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OutputDestination, nil, currentDest);
```

Im not too sure of the exact syntax, so you'll have to mess around with it a bit, but you should get the general idea.

Comment: kAudioSessionProperty_OutputDestinations 
>A CFArrayRef object containing details on the available audio output destinations in a USB audio accessory attached through the iPad camera connection kit.
Each element of the array contains a CFDictionaryRef object with the keys and corresponding values described in “USB Accessory Audio Destination Dictionary Keys.”

I can't use this because its only used for USB connected devices.

Comment: I figured out how to get the audio out put of the device but can't answer my own question just yet because i'm a noob and don't have 100+ rep. I will post the answer in 5 hours :)